# Количество колонок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть ли возможность с помощью css сделать, чтобы css-свойство `columns` создавало 3 колонки только в том случае, если количество `li` превышает 3 ?
а если число `li` меньше 3х, тогда `li` должен быть выровнен вертикально
https://jsfiddle.net/LkLhzwch/

```css
ul{
  columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

или как это реализовать, пусть с помощью других css-свойств?

Comment: нельзя, только js'ом считать кол-во и задавать модификатор.

Answer (score 1):

Можете добиться такого результата с помощью `flex`:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 3 33%;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(1),
ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

ul li+li+li:nth-last-child(1),
ul li+li:nth-last-child(2) {
  flex: 1 3 33% !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: так в вашем примере не то что нужно.
нужно чтобы если li 2 штуки, тогда эти li должны быть выровнены вертикально

Comment: Исправила, но для того чтобы задать обратную зависимость пришлось развернуть список задом наперед. Не знаю на сколько это вам удобно будет, да и семантически это наверняка не очень правильно. Но все же работает. Других вариантов без js в голову не приходит.